# Publishing python package into azure artifacts

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server, twine

Due to poor documentation I'm suffering alot to upload my Python Package to my internal Azure Artifacts:
I have followed exactly like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/twine-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

Twine authenticate was successful however unable to upload to feed as it keeps asking username!

Is my setup correct? I need to self authenticate the publish without providing username and password

Tools:

- Twine  - latest
- Azure-keyring - latest
- keyring - latest
- Python 3.10

Azure steps:

```
    - task: TwineAuthenticate@1
        inputs:
          artifactFeed: feedName
        displayName: Twine Authenticate
    
   - script: | 
      twine upload -r feedName --config-file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\.pypirc dist/*.whl
     displayName: Publish Package1
```

PyPirc file:

```
[distutils]
Index-servers =
  feedName

[feedName]
Repository = https://<host>/tfs/***-Collection/_packaging/feedName/pypi/upload
```

Starting: Twine Authenticate

```
=======================================================================
Task         : Python twine upload authenticate....
=======================================================================
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
Adding authentication to configuration for registry Neon
Successfully added auth for 1 internal feed and 0 external endpoint.
Finishing: Twine Authenticate
```

Starting: Publish Package

```
Uploading distributions to 
https://******/tfs/****-Collection/_packaging/****/pypi/upload
INFO     dist\***_test_framework-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 KB)              
INFO     Querying keyring for username                                         
WARNING  Error getting username from keyring                                   
         Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
           File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\auth.py", line 59, in    
         get_username_from_keyring                                             
             creds = keyring.get_credential(system, None)                      
           File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyring\core.py", line 72, in  
         get_credential                                                        
             return get_keyring().get_credential(service_name, username)       
           File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyring\backends\chainer.py",  
         line 71, in get_credential                                            
             credential = keyring.get_credential(service, username)            
           File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\artifacts_keyring\__init__.py",
         line 58, in get_credential                                            
             username, password = provider.get_credentials(service)     
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
               File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\artifacts_keyring\plugin.py",  
             line 67, in get_credentials                                           
                 username, password =                                              
             self._get_credentials_from_credential_provider(url, is_retry=False)   
               File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\artifacts_keyring\plugin.py",  
             line 124, in _get_credentials_from_credential_provider                
                 raise RuntimeError("Failed to get credentials: process with PID   
             {pid} exited with code {code}; additional error message: {error}"     
             RuntimeError: Failed to get credentials: process with PID 164 exited  
             with code 2; additional error message:                                
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\__main__.py", line 51, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\__main__.py", line 33, in main
        error = cli.dispatch(sys.argv[1:])
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\cli.py", line 123, in dispatch
        return main(args.args)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\commands\upload.py", line 198, in main
        return upload(upload_settings, parsed_args.dists)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\commands\upload.py", line 127, in upload
        repository = upload_settings.create_repository()
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\settings.py", line 329, in create_repository
        self.username,
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\settings.py", line 131, in username
        return cast(Optional[str], self.auth.username)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\auth.py", line 34, in username
        return utils.get_userpass_value(
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\utils.py", line 248, in get_userpass_value
        value = prompt_strategy()
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\auth.py", line 85, in username_from_keyring_or_prompt
        return self.prompt("username", input)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twine\auth.py", line 96, in prompt
        return how(f"Enter your {what}: ")
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting $(PYPIRC_PATH) on your twine upload step, this file will be auto-generated by the Twine_Authenticate task

**Example:**

- task: PowerShell@2

  inputs:

  targetType: 'inline'

  script: C:\Python310\python -m twine upload -r <feed_name> --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*.whl --non-interactive --skip-existing --verbose

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this fixed my issue and I have uploaded successfully

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test on my side, and it works fine:

**Project Scope Feed:**

***yml file***

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
- name: PYPIRC_PATH
  value: .pypirc

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      pip install wheel
      pip install twine
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'python setup.py bdist_wheel'

- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: '<Project Name>/<Feed Name>'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'python -m twine upload -r <Feed Name> --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*.whl'
```

***.pypirc***

```
[distutils]
Index-servers =
  <Organization Name>

[<Organization Name>]
Repository = https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_packaging/<Feed Name>/pypi/upload
```

**Organization Scope Feed:**

***yml file***

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
- name: PYPIRC_PATH
  value: .pypirc

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      pip install wheel
      pip install twine
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'python setup.py bdist_wheel'

- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: '<Organization Scope Feed Name>'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'python -m twine upload -r <Organization Scope Feed Name> --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*.whl'
```

***.pypirc***

```
[distutils]
Index-servers =
  <Organization Name>

[<Organization Name>]
Repository = https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_packaging/<Organization Scope Feed Name>/pypi/upload
```

Please refer to this official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-cli?view=azure-devops-2022

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm doing exactly as you said. As I mentioned before Twine Authenticate was successful however the Twine upload still ask for keyring username.
One observation for me if I add an environment variable in one task then on the next task it disappears, means every task runs like its own sandbox.. Could that means the authentication is not preserved for the next task?

Comment: Added a picture of CI run